# Block executing .msi if setup.exe exists

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have Basic MSI InstallShield project,
The setup include .msi and the setup.exe that launch the redistributable installations.
I'm sure there is some property I can use that prevent users from running the .msi and not the setup.exe
Can someone give me a hint ?

Comment: Can't you simply skip the MSI (i.e. set the release to "compressed" instead of "uncompressed" in the IS release options)? My memory may be fuzzy but as far as I remember this should include MSI into EXE.

Answer (score 0):

Check for ISSETUPDRIVEN public property and install launch condition.